# Can not change state of object

Tags: reactjs, axios, fetch, react-hooks, use-state

I am trying to fetch a single object, and it fetches, I get correct data in response.data, but i can't set it to state. It just remains as a null object. What am I doing wrong?
Post is a json object with several fields like: post_id, post_title, post_content and etc.

```
const [post, setPost] = useState({})

let id = match.params.id

useEffect(() => {
     axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/post?id=${id}`)
     .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)
        setPost(response.data)
     })
     .then(() => {
            console.log("post: ", post)
        }
     )
```

Comment: Post isn't reassigned until the *next* time the component is rendered.

Answer (score 1):

setAction like your `setPost` are asynchronous, as stated in the official REACT documentation (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate); this means that, once the setAction is executed, you don't know when it will be actually executed and terminated: you will know because the component will re-render.

In your case, if you'd like to perform action AFTER `post` has got the new value, you would need the `useEffect` hook (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect):

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  console.log(post);
}, [post]);
```

<s>By the way, I  think you would want the data inside the `response`, so you would probably save the JSON retrieved from the body of the HTTP Response, that you can get using `response.json()`.</s>

**EDIT:** As stated in the comment from Siradji Awoual, what I wrote about `response` and `response.json()` is not valid for Axios (but it still is for `fetch` API).

Comment: Actually, you don't need to do that when using axios. That will be true if you use something like fetch.

Comment: Oh sorry, while writing the answer I lost that particular (using Axios). I'm gonna edit the asnwer.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a state is asynchronous. That means you don't know exactly when that action will finish executing.

If I were you, I would use something like useEffect to check if the state is being set.

```js
React.useEffect(() => console.log(post), [post])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `axios.get` is low-level and requires that you hook up a bunch of extra stuff to get things working correctly. Instead, try writing custom hooks to abstract this logic away -

```js
const identity = x => x

const useAsync = (runAsync = identity, deps = []) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)
  const [result, setResult] = useState(null)

  useEffect(_ => { 
    Promise.resolve(runAsync(...deps))
      .then(setResult, setError)
      .finally(_ => setLoading(false))
  }, deps)

  return { loading, error, result }
}
```

Using `useAsync` looks like this -

```js
const MyApp = () => {
  const { loading, error, result } =
    useAsync(_ => axios.get("./foo.json").then(res => res.json()))

  if (loading)
    return <p>loading...</p>

  if (error)
    return <p>error: {error.message}</p>

  return <pre>result: {result}</pre>
}
```

But you will probably have many components that fetch JSON, right? We can make an even higher level custom hook, `useJSON` that is a specialization of `useAsync` -

```js
const fetchJson = (url = "") =>
  axios.get(url).then(r => r.json()) // <-- stop repeating yourself

const useJson = (url = "") =>
  useAsync(fetchJson, [url]) // <-- useAsync

const MyApp = () => {
  const { loading, error, result } =
    useJson("./foo.json")  // <-- dead simple

  if (loading)
    return <p>loading...</p>

  if (error)
    return <p>error: {error.message}</p>

  return <pre>result: {result}</pre>
}
```

See the custom hooks in action in this functioning code snippet -

```js
const { useState, useEffect } =
  React

// fake fetch slows response down so we can see loading
const _fetch = (url = "") =>
  fetch(url).then(x =>
    new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000, x)))

const identity = x => x

const useAsync = (runAsync = identity, deps = []) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)
  const [result, setResult] = useState(null)

  useEffect(_ => { 
    Promise.resolve(runAsync(...deps))
      .then(setResult, setError)
      .finally(_ => setLoading(false))
  }, deps)

  return { loading, error, result }
}

const fetchJson = (url = "") =>
  _fetch(url).then(r => r.json())

const useJson = (url = "") =>
  useAsync(fetchJson, [url])

const MyComponent = ({ url = "" }) => {
  const { loading, error, result } =
    useJson(url)

  if (loading)
    return <pre>loading...</pre>

  if (error)
    return <pre style={{color: "tomato"}}>error: {error.message}</pre>

  return <pre>result: {JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)}</pre>
}

const MyApp = () =>
  <main>
    ex 1 (success):
    <MyComponent url="https://httpbin.org/get?foo=bar" />

    ex 2 (error):
    <MyComponent url="https://httpbin.org/status/500" />
  </main>

ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.body)
```

```css
pre {
  background: ghostwhite;
  padding: 1rem;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```